# Nested Structures/Unions defined in C/C++ header files in XML by Reflection

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reflection

I have a structure represented as follows: (Example)

```
struct struct3
{
   struct structchild4
   {  
      float child5;
   } child6;
   unsigned int child7;
};
```

I want this to be represented as follows in XML:

```
<tag1= "struct3">
        <name>struct3</name>
        <input_type>byte</input_type>
        <method></method>
        <tag_ref = "structchild4">
            <name>child6</name>
        </tag_ref>
        <tag2= "child7">
            <name>child7</name>
            <len>4</len>
            <value> </value>
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
```

The method I'm following is that I'm converting this into a gccXML format and I then parse it using Visual C++. I use the xerces-c DOM parser.

Could anyone suggest how to go about doing this? A gentle bounce on this. Is there anyway I can send my code? Its huge and exceeds the character limit. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, you're going to parse the header files using gccXML and parse the resulting XML using the Xerces DOM parser, have I got that right?, what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: The task at hand is to convert a C/C++ header file into a specified XML format. So, I do the following operations on the header file:

1) Convert the header file into a gccXML format by using gccXML
2) The resulting XML is parsed using the Xerces-c DOM Parser.

I want to try out reflection. The gccXML does not have enough information to construct the XML as desired. I feel. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, @GearoidMurphy you're right.

Comment: "gccXML does not have enough information".  Are you sure?  What information does it lack?  If it does lack information [you show an example of "size" which I expect isn't in the *type* information exported by gccXML], you have difficult choices: a) revise gccXML itself (open source!) to add the information you need, b) switch to some other infrastructure that can provide this information.

Comment: ... when you get your "ideal" XML output, then what? What has "reflection" got to do with this, unless you mean "reflection as a means to get information about the code base"?

Comment: I want to switch to some other way to parse nested structures/unions as shown in the example.
For instance, the gccXML description of struct3 is the following:

<Struct id="_26" name="struct3" context="_1" mangled="7struct3" location="f1:76" file="f1" line="76" artificial="1" size="64" align="32" members="_781 _782 _783 _784 _785 " bases=""/>

I'm not able to figure out how to use this to generate the XML that I need.

Answer (score 1):

As you're already aware, gccXML has some significant limitations, there are a number of open source C++ parsers described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526797/good-tools-for-creating-a-c-c-parser-analyzer). Unfortunately, relfection in C++ is a lot of work for the coder (but an excellent exercise nonetheless), my favoured approach is to use the [clang python API](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/), clang is an excellent C++ parser but it's up to you to decide how to process that information (by outputting to XML or JSON). There used to be an [XML printer for Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309405/can-i-get-an-xml-ast-dump-of-c-c-code-with-clang-without-using-the-compiler) but unfortunately I don't believe it's still active, you may be able to use an earlier build though. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you @Gearoid Murphy. The final output of my code has to be in a particular XML format. The catch is that for parsing functions, enums, typedefs etc I have used the gccXML description and xerces-c DOM Parser. Will I be able to use CLang just for structures? Rather, will I be able to give preferential treatment to just structures? Thank you!