# Parsing Stage output of C source file in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I have a .c source file and i want to analysis the output of the source file after parsing stage of gcc and generate report on basis of it.what could be the possible methods to do so
How can i do this with gcc

In case of preprocessing the code can be generated by passing -E argument to gcc but what would be the way to do to generate parsed output of the code only??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see parse tree, intermediate code, optimization code and assembly code during COMPILATION?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496497/how-can-i-see-parse-tree-intermediate-code-optimization-code-and-assembly-code)

Comment: @nhahtdh what "-fdump-tree-all" really does??

Comment: @nhahtdh the question doesn't have enough answers, I can't rely on it for my query

Comment: can I recommend `clang`? it has really nice tools for these kind of tasks. nice colored trees blossoming in the spring...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath but there must some way where you can generate ast in xml format through gcc of c source file .is there way around for this?

Comment: @user4255847: surely there is (if there isn't, write your own extension)... I just tried to be pragmatic.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath but according to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309405/can-i-get-an-xml-ast-dump-of-c-c-code-with-clang-without-using-the-compiler?rq=1 xml support is ommited in clang

Comment: @user4255847: uh.. 2.8? :) dunno. are you sure you want XML? the language is so (ridiculously) complex I doubt you need the complete AST, analysing the complete tree is an immense task. My guess would be you need stats on some *specific* things. In that case, clang has nice support for extensions for the whole toolchain (haven't tried it though)... just intercept the things you're interested in. Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @KarolyHorvath to clear things so we don't lead further in XY problem: i am trying to obtain output of soure file(xy.c) when it is passed to parser take ex: gcc(it is more i am familiar with) and that would be an ast and based on that generate report in xml format for some xml template purposes??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath hey buddy as you suggested to use clang to generate ast in xml i use "-ast-dump-xml" with clang but it return error:unknown argument: '-ast-dump-xml'. so what should i do now??